# how to check if file exists using zend validator - zend framework 2.0

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

the following is an example I am putting together on how to use Zend Validator to check if a file exists.

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_File_Exists();
$validator->addDirectory('/users/images/');

if($validator->isValid('testimage.jpg')){
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false"; 
}
```

The above code keeps returning false for me... perhaps I am using the validator in the wrong way, or my syntax is incorrect... either way I was not able to find the proper documentation on the Zend website.. surprise, surprise... any help here would be appreciated. cheers

Answer (score 0):

yup, it was a syntax error... apparently there was not 'images' folder created...

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_File_Exists();
$validator->addDirectory('users/');

if($validator->isValid('testimage.jpg')){
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false"; 
}
```